# SQL query to aggregate month in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with one column (`TK`) with multiple values, also duplicated and another one column with date.

I need to return a table with first column with `distinct(TK)` and the other columns like month.

I do an example into SQL FIDDLE

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/14cb9f/28

| TK | JANUARY |
| --- | --- |
| open a | 4 |
| open B | 4 |

| TK | FEBRUARY |
| --- | --- |
| open a | 4 |
| open B | 4 |

I need

| TK | JANUARY | FEBRUARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| open a | 4 | 4 |
| open B | 4 | 4 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
SELECT TK
      ,Janary   = sum( case when month(datastart)=1 then 1 else 0 end )
      ,February = sum( case when month(datastart)=2 then 1 else 0 end )
 From  TEST
 Where year(datastart)=2021
 Group By TK
```

Or you can use `PIVOT`

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select TK
              ,Col = datename(month,DataStart) 
              ,Val = 1
         From TEST
         Where year(datastart)=2021
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Val) for Col in ([January] ,[February] ) ) pvt
```

Comment: Maybe better use `WHERE datastart >= '2021-01-01' AND datastart < '2022-01-01'` instead of `WHERE year(datastart) = 2021` so that an index including `datastart` can be used?

Comment: @stickybit No doubt.  I just tossed the WHERE in there as an afterthought just in case there were multiple years.   Then again, the WHERE may not be required if OP is doing profiles by month.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but avoiding sub-queries and making the syntax simple to read, this is the simplest I can get:

```
SELECT
  TK,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATASTART >= '2021-01-01' AND DATASTART < '2021-02-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS JENUARY,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATASTART >= '2021-02-01' AND DATASTART <= '2021-02-28' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS FEBRUARY
FROM
  Test
GROUP BY
  TK
```

Check it out
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/14cb9f/34

Comment: Thank you for your help.